# Logout from access control service with custom STS

Tags: windows, azure, acs

I'm using Windows azure access control service with custom STS. I can login to my application through ACS, but I have trouble with logout function. I've tried this code in my application.

```
        WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

        try
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
        finally
        {
            fam.SignOut(true);
        }
        Page.Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
```

But it seems that it logout the user from ACS but not from the custom STS. What should I do to logout from STS. Where could be the problem in the appliacation (RP), ACS or in STS?

I think that ACS should ask custom STS to logout the user, but it seems it doesnt do that. What I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

I have created a helper method for doing FederatedSignout, with comments in the code for what I discovered along the way (hth)

```
public static void FederatedSignOut(string reply = null)
{
   WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

   // Native FederatedSignOut doesn't seem to have a way for finding/registering realm for singout, get it from the FAM
   string wrealm = string.Format("wtrealm={0}", fam.Realm);

   // Create basic url for signout (wreply is set by native FederatedSignOut)
   string signOutUrl = WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(fam.Issuer, null, wrealm);

   // Check where to return, if not set ACS will use Reply address configured for the RP
   string wreply = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reply) ? reply : (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fam.Reply) ? fam.Reply : null);

   WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(signOutUrl), !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wreply) ? new Uri(wreply) : null);

   // Remarks! Native FederatedSignout has an option for setting signOutUrl to null, even if the documentation tells otherwise.
   // If set to null the method will search for signoutUrl in Session token, but I couldn't find any information about how to set this. Found some Sharepoint code that use this
   // Michele Leroux Bustamante had a code example (from 2010) that also uses this form.
   // Other examples creates the signout url manually and calls redirect.

   // FAM has support for wsignoutcleanup1.0 right out of the box, there is no need for code to handle this.
   // That makes it even harder to understand why there are no complete FederatedSignOut method in FAM

   // When using native FederatedSignOut() no events for signout will be called, if you need this use the FAM SignOut methods instead.
}
```

This code is used in a standard RP library we created for Web SSO with ACS.

Answer (score 2):

The December 2012 update of ACS includes support for federated single sign-out:

> Using the WS-Federation protocol. Web applications that use ACS to
>   enable single sign-on (SSO) with identity providers using the
>   WS-Federation protocol can now take advantage of single sign out
>   capabilities. When a user signs out of a web application, ACS can
>   automatically sign the user out of the identity provider and out of
>   other relying party applications that use the same identity provider.
>
> This feature is enable for WS-Federation identity providers, including
>   Active Directory Federation Services 2.0 and Windows Live ID
>   (Microsoft account). To enable single sign out, ACS performs the
>   following tasks for WS-Federation protocol endpoints:
>
> - ACS recognizes wsignoutcleanup1.0 messages from identity providers
>     and responds by sending wsignoutcleanup1.0 messages to relying party
>     applications.
> - ACS recognizes wsignout1.0 and wreply messages from relying party
>     applications and responds by sending wsignout1.0 messages to identity
>     providers and wsignoutcleanup1.0 messages to relying party
>     applications.

From the [Code Sample: ASP.NET MVC 4 with Federated Sign-out](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/jj984618.aspx), implement an Action like this to sign out from ACS:

(Note that Windows Identity Foundation is now incorporated into .NET 4.5 Framework, that's why the new namespaces below)

```
using System.IdentityModel.Services;
using System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration;

public ActionResult Logout()
{
    // Load Identity Configuration
    FederationConfiguration config = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration;

    // Get wtrealm from WsFederationConfiguation Section
    string wtrealm = config.WsFederationConfiguration.Realm;
    string wreply;

    // Construct wreply value from wtrealm (This will be the return URL to your app)
    if (wtrealm.Last().Equals('/'))
    {
        wreply = wtrealm + "Logout";
    }
    else
    {
        wreply = wtrealm + "/Logout";
    }

    // Read the ACS Ws-Federation endpoint from web.Config
    // something like "https://<your-namespace>.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation"
    string wsFederationEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Issuer"];

    SignOutRequestMessage signoutRequestMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(wsFederationEndpoint));

    signoutRequestMessage.Parameters.Add("wreply", wreply);
    signoutRequestMessage.Parameters.Add("wtrealm", wtrealm);

    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();

    string signoutUrl = signoutRequestMessage.WriteQueryString();

    return this.Redirect(signoutUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking all over for a solution like this. Worked like a charm.